# Spyder installed, now conda commands do not work

Tags: python, configuration, spyder

I'm brand new to Python and I have a virtual machine using Windows with my company and installed spyder.  I tried to run it but all I get is a command prompt that quickly flashes on, then off.  It is too quick to discern what the error message is.

Now, any 'conda xxx' command I run, I get the following error message:

Error: could not import yaml (required to read .condarc config file:  C\Miniconda.condarc)

Answer (score 0):

looks like pyyaml is missing. Install with

```
$ conda install pyyaml
```

or

```
$ pip install pyyaml
```